# TreeSets and removing specific unnamed Objects

Tags: java, object, tree, set

So I'm writing a program for an assignment where I store Patients into a TreeSet. The problemn I'm having is I have to implement a method to discharge a specefic patient from the TreeSet.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        Random ag = new Random();
        int age = ag.nextInt(99) + 1;
        Names randomname = Names.getRandom();
        String name = randomname.name();
        String sex;
        if(Math.random() > 0.5)sex = "female";
        else sex = "male";
        Random sn = new Random();
        int serial = sn.nextInt(10000) + 1;
        Address randomAddress = Address.getRandom();
        String address = randomAddress.name();
        Hospital.admitPatient(new Patient(age, name, sex, serial, Birthday.produceBirthday(), address));
    }
```

So Thats how I am looping to get the Patients info and stats for the Patient Object. The admit patient method adds them to the TreeSet.

```
public static void admitPatient(Patient obj){
    if(numofPatients < maxPatients){
        patientList1.add(obj);
    }
}
```

The Problem I'm having is withbthe Discharge patient method. Where I don't know what to put in the method

```
public static void dischargePatient(What do i put here in the driver when i call this method?){
    patientList1.remove(w/e i put up there);
```

}

Since I didn't name the Objects of patients when creating them but just inserted them straight into the TreeSet I'm not sure exactly how to call them when i call the discharge patient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you usually want to work with selected objects (patients) and not the whole list, you need a way to identify them somehow (for example by name or ID).

Since `add` and `remove` are similar, your `dischargePatient` method will be similar as well. Try

```
public static void dischargePatient(Patient patient) {
     patientList1.remove(patient);
}
```

To retrieve a patient with a certain ID, you may iterate through your set and return it:

```
public Patient getPatientByID(String id) {
    for (Patient patient : patientList1) {
        if (patient.getID().equals(id)) {
            return patient;
        }
    }
}
```

To remove a patient with ID "1234abc", you could do the following:

```
dischargePatient(getPatientByID("1234abc"));
```

Using this pattern, you rebuild the functionality of the map datastructure. Thus it might be better to use a Map (e.g. HashMap<>). Code will be reduced to operations like:

```
Map<String, Patient> patients = new HashMap<>();
patients.put("1234abc", patient1);  
patients.remove("1234abc");
```

Full code for your example:

```
public static void admitPatient(Patient patient) {
    if(numofPatients < maxPatients){
        patients.put(patient.getID(), patient);
    }
}

public static void dischargePatient(String id) {
    patients.remove(id);
}
```